# OpenServer CORS

Tags: javascript, php, cors

Тестирую всякие штуки, столкнулся с проблемой. 
Пытаюсь со страницы отправить POST на localhost, получаю такую ошибку:

`has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Как это починить? Даже не понимаю где такая настройка может быть. Или на localhost вообще нельзя кросс доменные запросы слать?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/macloud/blog/553826/

Answer (score 0):

Можно отключить проверку в браузере. Параметром при запуске:

```
chromium-browser --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="[some directory here]"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome